# Updating List in SharePoint 2010 from VS 2010 and Soap Server Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, list, exception, service, sharepoint-2010

My question is for updating the LIST in SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2010 from WPF Project. I use SharePoint Foundation 2010, running on my laptop with Windows 7 64.

Here is a code snippet where Im trying to do that and were I have an expecption

```
 WPFSPListApp.MySPWebService.Lists myListService = new MySPWebService.Lists();

        myListService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    myListService.Url = "http://pc_name/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        XmlNode myListView = myListService.GetListAndView("Customers", "");
```

At line XmlNode myListView I have this expeception:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
```

In SharePoint I have the List "Customers" created.

I have read a lot of pages, but nothig helped. I use WebReference, I use my pc name in url, when I give this url in my browser, im asked for login/pass that I use in my Windows Account.

Im new by SharePoint, so please if my description isnt enough - please ask me!

Thank you very much!

P.S. Exception Description if needed:

```
  System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled
  Message=Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
  Source=System.Web.Services
  Actor=""
  Lang=""
  Node=""
  Role=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at WPFSPListApp.MySPWebService.Lists.GetListAndView(String listName, String viewName) in c:\users\kot\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WPFSPListApp\WPFSPListApp\Web References\MySPWebService\Reference.cs:line 262
       at WPFSPListApp.MainWindow.btnUpdate_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\users\kot\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WPFSPListApp\WPFSPListApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 51
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at WPFSPListApp.App.Main() in c:\users\kot\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WPFSPListApp\WPFSPListApp\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: try CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

Comment: Thanks, but it isnt working. Should I use my pc name in Service.Url or localhost adress? Because I dont know what could it more be..

Answer (score 0):

Try to get only the list

```
XmlNode myListView = myListService.GetList("Customers");
```

If it would be work, then it means, that you sent wrong view name (it should be guid).

Comment: Thanks moskalevN, but it didnt work. I have turned my Firewall off, I have turn on Intranet Settings, I have tryed with <pc_name> and <localhost> in URL.  My Question isnt solved! Please, if you have more ideas - share it with me!